# Django ImportError

Tags: python, django, importerror, python-import

I created my own Django application with directory structure

```
/appname
    __init__.py
    models.py
    /submodule1
        __init__.py
        a.py
```

Inside `a.py` I have the following import

```
from ..models import Something
```

This works okay if I have `/appname` inside my `/djangoproject` folder, but when I install the app to Python's site-packages (via `setup.py` which I created), all hell breaks loose and `a.py` can no longer import `Something`, with the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Something
```

Here is the setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='appname',
      version='0.1',
      packages=['appname', 'appname.contrib'],
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that it was a circular import error. `models.py` was importing `a.py` and `a.py` was importing `models.py`.

Breaking this circle solved the import issues, but now it is time to figure out how to do lazy evaluation in Python :-)

Comment: I've run into this myself, I just put the import statement inside the function that required `a.py` but that seems icky. What was your solution?

Answer (score 3):

Put empty file named: `__init__.py` inside /submodule1 so Python can parse it as module. It should help. The same in /appname - there should be also `__init__.py` file

Comment: Yes I had `__init__.py` in both `/submodule1` and `/` but it is still giving me the `ImportError`.